# migrated site from asp.net into mvc3, now setting up 301's

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I have just about finished migrating a asp.net 3.5 site into mvc3.

The whole site structure is coming different now e.g.

www.mysite.com/about-us.aspx is now www.mysite/about-us
www.mysite.com/where-to-use.aspx?city=london is now www.mysite.com/where-to-use/london

Im using IIS7.5, how do I setup the 301 redirect? to avoid any SEO problems?

Any pointers would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up an custom http handler and capture requests to your "old" URLs and then do a 301.

However, the best way to maintain your SEO strength would be to update your routes to continue to use the .aspx extension. I know it's not as pretty, but this will guarantee that you won't lose pages in indexes, rankings or other general SEO strength of your site.